# Manifolds with polynomial transition maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, polynomials, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**Title edited** I  thank  მამუკა ჯიბლაძე  and  Corbennick for  their  suggestion on the  title  of this  question. I  changed the  title based on the suggestion of  Corbennick.

What is an example of a manifold $M$ which does not admit an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ with the following property?:

For every two charts $(\phi,U)$ and $(\psi,V)$ in $\mathcal{A}$, $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a polynomial map.(Its  components are  polynomial  functions).

**Motivation:** The  motivation for this  question comes  from the  concept ["Affine  manifolds"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold). I  am  indebted to [Mike  Cocos,](https://mathoverflow.net/users/70498/mike-cocos)  for  learning this concept and its  related problem, that is  Chern  conjecture.

Comment: Good question, bad title :D

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  May I ask you to suggest a new title? Thank you.

Comment: How about: Manifolds with polynomial transition maps?

Comment: @Corbennick  Thank you!very  good  suggestion.

Comment: The Wikipedia page that you link to shows that there are lots of (necessarily non-simply connected but) very natural and important examples of compact manifolds with not only polynomial but even affine transition maps, like e. g. flat tori. I find it very interesting question whether there are any essentially non-affine examples, i. e. compact manifolds which do not admit atlases with affine transition maps but admit atlases with some higher degree polynomial transition maps.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  That  is  a very  interesting question. May be another question: Is there  a  compact  manifold  with  polynomial transition maps  but  its  Euler  characteristic is non zero?

Comment: ..Motivated by Chern conjecture.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is impossible for any (nonempty) simply-connected compact manifold of positive dimension.  In particular, $S^2$ cannot have such an atlas.  Off the top of my head, I don't remember where I saw this statement, but I'll try to find a reference.

Followup:  I still don't remember the reference, but I think that the proof goes something like this:

By hypothesis, both $\tau=\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ and $\sigma = \phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ are polynomial maps, and hence they are defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  By hypothesis there is a nonempty open domain $D_1\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\sigma(\tau(x)) = x$ for all $x\in D_1$ and a nonempty open domain $D_2\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\tau(\sigma(y)) = y$ for all $y\in D_2$.  Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are polynomial mappings, it follows that $\sigma(\tau(x)) = x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau(\sigma(y)) = y$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Thus, $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are globally invertible.  Moreover, by the chain rule, we have $\sigma'(\tau(x))\tau'(x) = I$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and, taking determinants, it follows that $\det(\tau'(x))$ and $\det(\sigma'(\tau(x)))$, which are polynomial in $x$ must actually be (nonzero) constants.

Consequently, it follows that $\Lambda^n(T^*M)$ carries a (unique) flat connection such that, if $\mathrm{d}x$ is the standard volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\psi^*(\mathrm{d}x)$ is a (local) parallel section of $\Lambda^n(T^*M)$ for each $(\psi,U)$ in the atlas $\mathcal{A}$.  By simple-connectivity, there is a global parallel volume form $\mu$ on $M$, and we can, composing the members of our atlas with linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$, get a new atlas with polynomial transitions that satisfies $\psi^*(\mathrm{d}x) = \mu$ on $U$ for all $(\psi,U)$ in the new atlas.

There is also a way to analytically continue the map $\psi$ coming from a chart $(\psi,U)$ to the domain $U\cup V$ for any chart $(\phi,V)$ for which $U\cap V$ is non-empty:  Since $\tau$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and since $\psi = \tau\circ\phi$ on $U\cap V$, one can take $\psi(q) = \tau(\phi(q))$ for all $q\in V$, which extends $\psi$ to $V$.

Using this construction, any $(\psi,U)\in\mathcal{A}$ can be uniquely analytically continued along any smooth path in $M$, and one easily verifies that this extension depends only on the homotopy class of the path with fixed endpoints.  Since $M$ is simply connected, this means that $\psi$ can be extended uniquely analytically to all of $M$, and hence $\psi:M\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map that satisfies $\psi^*(\mathrm{d}x) = \mu$ on all of $M$.  Obviously, this is impossible.

Comment: Where are you using the volume form?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie:  I could have got away without it, but it was convenient to be able to write that $\psi^*(\mathrm{d}x)=\mu$ globally, which made the contradiction obvious, since, otherwise, it was not immediate (to me) that the analytic continuation of $\psi$ would always be a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: What about if the transition functions are rational functions? This includes the sphere, for example.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you very much for your interesting answer. What is the role  of  connection in your answer? Am I mistaken to think that $\psi^* (dx)=\mu$ is globally true because both sides are real analytic and they are equal only in a given arbitrary chart?(By analytic  continuation).

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  The (flat) connection provides a global volume form with respect to which all the coordinate charts are unimodular.  Then, yes, the fact that $\psi$ is analytic on $U$ and has a unique analytic continuation to all of $M$ coupled with the fact that $\mu$ is analytic on the whole of $M$ implies that the analytically continued $\psi$ satisfies $\psi^*(\mathrm{d}x)=\mu$ globally, since these analytic functions are equal on a nonempty open set.

Comment: @RobertBryant  What would be the mistake of this  simplification of  your  argument: With re scaling,   we  have  an atlas whose transition maps  satisfy $Det (f')=1$ (rather than arbitrary constant) So  we  have easily  an analytic  volume  form $\mu$  globally  on $M$. Now  we extend  $\psi$ to $M$ uniquely. Again we  have $\psi^* (dx)=\mu$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  How could you determine how to scale the members of your atlas so as to arrange that the transitions are all unimodular?  You need to use simple-connectivity somewhere, otherwise, it may not be possible.  For example, consider the quotient $M^2$ of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ by the scaling $(x,y)\mapsto(2x,2y)$, which is a torus.  Let the atlas $\mathcal{A}$ consist of the local sections of the quotient mapping $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to M^2$ with small circular domains.  You cannot scale the members of $\mathcal{A}$ to obtain a unimodular atlas $\mathcal{A}'$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  In  my  previous  comment  I  am  still assuming  simple  connectivity for  such rescaling. Is this  re scalling  legal(with  simple  connectivity)? So we  have  a  global volum form then we  extend  $\psi$ analytically then we  have $\psi^* (dx)=\mu$. So  I  do not  understant the  necessity of "connecdtion". I would  appreciate if  you more  explain.

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  The question is *how* do you do the rescaling?  You need to produce a decision procedure to determine how to scale each member of the given atlas so as to get a new atlas with unimodular transitions.  I am saying that you need to specify exactly *how* you are using the hypothesis of simple-connectivity to construct this decision procedure before I will believe that you know how to do it.  The way I chose (although it could be avoided by an appeal to Cech cohomology) was to construct a flat connection and then appeal to simple-connectivity to provide the global flat section $\mu$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  This was the  procedure which I was thinking  about  but now  I realize  may be it  does  not  work: we  fix a  base point  p on M. For  every  q we  choose a  curve  $\gamma$ joining  p to q. We  cover the  curve  with open sets such that two consecutive  open sets  have  non empty  intersection. then there  is  an  obvious  rescaling. to prove  that this  is  independent  of  choosing the curve  we use  simple  connectivity.  May  be  this  is  my  fault?  Now  I understand Cech cohomology or the connection you  constructed  are two possible approach.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Now I  understand the  details of  your interesting answer. Thank you  for  your patient on my slow  understanding.

Comment: @Kevin Casto: Maybe you ask that as a question.

Comment: @KevinCasto : Any compact $C^\infty$ manifold admits an atlas whose transition maps are rational by the Nash-Tognoli Theorem.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman:  Could you give a reference for this claim?  The Nash-Tognoli Theorem implies that every compact $C^\infty$ manifold is diffeomorphic to a real algebraic variety and hence admits an atlas with transition maps that are *algebraic*, but I don't see how one gets *rational* from this result.

Comment: @RobertBryant : Yeah, you'e right; a real algebraic variety is locally isomorphic to a closed algebraic subset of $R^n$, and not necessarily locally isomorphic to an open subset of $R^n$. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 21):

Brief sketch of slight simplification of Bryant's answer:

Without loss of generality $\mathcal A$ is maximal with respect to the condition that all transition functions are polynomial. Now make a space $\tilde M$ by gluing together $U$ and $V$ whenever $(\phi, U)$ and $(\psi,V)$ are charts such that $\phi$ and $\psi$ agree in $U\cap V$. This is a smooth manifold (or rather each of its connected components is), because polynomials are so rigid. It is equipped with both a covering projection to $M$ and an immersion in $\mathbb R^n$. So if $M$ is simply connected then $M$ immerses in $\mathbb R^n$. If $M$ is also compact and $n>0$ then this is impossible.

Comment: To explain why $\tilde M$ is a covering space of $M$: If a diffeomorphism between open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ is given by a polynomial formula and the same holds for the inverse diffeomorphism, then the same formulas give diffeomorphisms $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$. This fails if we say "rational" or analytic" rather than "polynomial".

Comment: Thank you  very  much for  your  answer. My  apology if my  question is  elementary: May I ask you to elaborate the  construction of  $\tilde{M}$?

Comment: For each chart $(\phi,U)$ in the atlas, take a copy of the space $U$; call it $U_\phi$. Form the disjoint union of $U_\phi$ over all charts. Now make a quotient space as follows. Given charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$, we identify a point $p\in U_\phi$ with a point $q\in V_\psi$ if and only if $p=q\in M$ and $\phi$ and $\psi$ coincide in some neighborhood of $p=q$. This quotient space is $\tilde M$.

Comment: For each connected chart in $\mathcal A$ the canonical map $U_\phi\to\tilde M$ maps $U_\phi$ homeomorphically to an open subset. The space $\tilde M$ is Hausdorff. There is a map $\pi:\tilde M\to M$ given by sending each $U_\phi$ to $U$ by "the identity". To see that $\pi$ is a covering projection, argue as follows. Suppose that $(U,\phi)$ is a chart in $\mathcal A$. Then, for every polynomial map $h:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ with polynomial inverse, $(U,h\circ\phi)$ is again a chart in $\mathcal A$. I claim that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of the open sets $U_{h\circ\phi}$.

Comment: Thank you  very  much  for  your  very  interesting answer and  your  supplementary comments on my commented question.I  am really  sorry that  I  can not  accept both answers  simultaneously.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for your interesting question.

Answer (score 8):

Let me develop Robert Bryant's answer :
if $M$ is a simply-connected manifold of dimension $n$ with a polynomial atlas, then there exists a local isomorphism $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Conversely, such a local isomorphism yields a polynomial atlas.

Indeed let $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_M$ be the subsheaf of polynomial functions (with respect to the given atlas). Then the pair $(M,\mathcal{F})$ is locally isomorphis to an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ together with the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. Thus $\mathcal{F}$ is a local system.

Since $M$ is simply-connected, the locally constant sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ is constant. Thus there is an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]_M \simeq \mathcal{F}$. The images of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are smooth functions on $M$,  which give a local isomorphism $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (compatible with the polynomial atlas).

Note that the map $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ has open non-empty image, hence non-compact image if $n >0$. Thus such a $M$ is never compact for $n>0$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a constant sheaf? The ones I know only admit sections corresponding to locally constant functions...

Comment: A constant sheaf is indeed the sheaf of locally constant functions with values in some given set. A locally constant sheaf (= local system) is a sheaf locally of this form. The latter are in $1$-$1$ correspondance with sets endowed with an action of the fundamental group $\pi$. The action is trivial (e.g. if $\pi = 1$) iff the sheaf is constant.

Comment: But the sections we need must be all polynomial functions, they are rarely locally constant?

Comment: If $U$ is a polynomial chart, then $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is the set of locally constant functions $U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, i.e. functions on $U$ which are polynomial on each connected component of $U$. This exactly what we want.

Comment: No I don't understand, sorry. Say, $M$ is $\mathbb R$;  ${\mathcal F}(M)$ contains a (global) section whose value at $x\in M$ is $x^2$. How to represent this section as a section of the constant sheaf associated to ${\mathbb R}[X]$? Say, one global section of the latter is the one with the same value $X^2$ at any $x$; but that's different, is not it?

Comment: Ok. I am identifying polynomials functions on a given connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. Is it what you wanted to point out ?

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry. There is an isomorphism of sheaves depending on chosen polynomial atlas. In fact giving such isomorphism should be more or less equivalent to giving a polynomial atlas. Thanks!

Comment: @js21  Thank  you very much  for  your  interesting answer which is  an inspiration for this   [MO  queston](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275721/a-way-to-twist-a-manifold?noredirect=1&lq=1).